# API for searching for specific places by proximity

Tags: api, google-maps, geolocation, location, google-places-api

I would like to return specific places (stores like Target, Macy's, etc.) by location (latitude, longitude).

I have been using the google places api  and entering the different stores in the name parameter.  The results are inconsistent at best.

Is this the api I should be using to return specific stores by name and proximity?  The google places api near by search has only a single name parameter. I would ideally like to search for several specific stores in a single request to the endpoint for performance reasons.

In conclusion
What api should I be using to return specific stores by name and proximity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Places API is the correct Google API to use; however, as you mentioned it does not support multiple `name` or `keyword` parameters. There is an active Places API - Feature Request for this [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4278), please star it if you wish to see it resolved and to be notified of future changes.

Instead of using the `name` parameter, try using the `keyword` parameter. The `keyword` parameter is matched against all available fields, including but not limited to name, type, and address, as well as customer reviews and other third-party content. This can often yield more or better results.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if the foursquare api does let you search for multiple specific places.

Here is an example url that does the trick:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=34.017717,-118.159335&query=Target Victoria's Secret Macy's &intent=browse&radius=16094&oauth_token=mytoken
g

So I'm abandoning Google Places and going with FourSquare.

Comment: I think the foursquare api changed because this is no longer working